# How to use exported function in another component in html? ANgular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have exported function in separated file

```
export function sum(population): string {
    return population.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
}
```

I am import this function in my component:

```
import { sum } from  '../../shared/utilities/globalFunction'
```

And how to use this sum in html ?

When i set

```
<p> {{ sum(variable-with-data) }}
```

no work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in html only can use "variables" public in ts, so you need declarea a "variable" (*) and use some like

```
//in .ts
mysum=sum

//in .html
{{mysum(variable-with-data)}}
```

Is like another one, you can not use Math in .html but you can use

```
//in .ts
myMath=Math

//in .html
{{myMat.cos(3.4)}}
```

(*) I say variable, ,but can be a class, an object a function...

Comment: Where to mysum=sum ? I am se to OnInit but again no work..

Comment: no, it's not necesary in ngOnInit, simply declare as any variable you need

Comment: hhmm weird.. i am set it but no work...maybe is error in exported function...

Comment: it's a fool example, but.. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-oymu7p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts